# How to test Wordpress plugin functions

Tags: wordpress, phpunit, mockery

How can I use PHPUnit to test functions in my Wordpress plugin that are not inside a class?  These functions are used as template tags.

**Edit 1**
I am using [WP_Mock](https://github.com/10up/wp_mock) from 10up.

My wordpress plugin provides some template tags from a single file and I am trying to test them.  In the example below I am testing a() and I want to mock b(), which is called by a().

I get an error message `Call to undefined function c()` so it seems my attempt to mock b() with WP_Mock::userFunction is failing.

Is this the expected behaviour?
How can I make a test double for b()?

```
// my-plugin-template-tags.php

<?php 

function a(){
    $val = b();
    return 'bar';
}

function b(){
    c();
}
```

```
// TemplateTagsTest.php

<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class TemplateTagsTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_a()
    {
        \WP_Mock::userFunction( 'b', array(
            'return' => 'foo'
        ) );

        $this->assertSame( 'bar', a() );
    }

    public function setUp() : void
    {
        \WP_Mock::setUp();
    }
    public function tearDown() : void
    {
        \WP_Mock::tearDown();
    }
}
```